# Reading float values without losing the precision

Tags: c

I have a dataset ((12008 * 12008) matrix stored as csv format ) containing floating-point numeric values such as:

```
0.00000000000000000129097521168892,0.00000822381709160264,-0.0000202130952444797,-0.0000242966927641499,0.000030546233920949,0.0000371753288365733,-0.00000425477255333099,0.0000417806937053693,-0.0000108963812606789,-0.0000116825931954974,0.00000630880107874073,-0.0000148294201214316,0.000015379692507603,0.00000188679818192867,0.00000244261959932239,-0.00000000000000000151132910441927,-0.0000219241408193178,0.000017429377110585,0.00000870784208574737,0.0000364006097348257,0.0000113488247245831,0.000000061277075989572,0.00000139732542828701,0.000000106947553933263,0.0000326417023213338,0.000000461629854407632,0.0000154355086839126,-0.00000952557006126632,-0.00000661974638741755,0.0000100492673229086,-0.00000234761929597247,0.000000562031028984242,-0.0000111189586356939,0.0000147613296909272,-0.0000412808264307332,0.0000144980218289582,-0.00000396573532860471,0.00000284216015813941,-0.000000340292198448977,0.000000000000000000673559708847384,-0.000000000000000000477244282125147,0.0000295672329145256,0.000000265057585538249,-0.0000259880981140332,-0.000000655572300400449,0.0000275203484322834,0.00000939709816031401,-0.000000722013848489603,-0.000000131975990695569,-0.0000305715257167805,0.0000166359409438876,-0.0000108549024616569,0.0000035413589251256,0.0000134733827428785,0.00000033136969072632,-0.0000000227012317723535,0.0000251344669810146,0.00000507204772254958,-0.00000000193093573409854,
```

I noticed when I read it to a float buffer, I lose the precision too much so I get something like:

```
0.0000000
-0.000082
```

I want to read the exact values from the dataset **without losing the precision** to a buffer in my program. I use the following small program to read but I am not sure how to modify it so that it does not lose the precision:

```
float *data = malloc((12008 * 12008) * sizeof(float));
FILE *fp ;
fp=fopen("./eig_matrix.csv","rb");
if(fp!= NULL) fread(data, (12008 * 12008)*sizeof(float),1,fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Until now, you don'Ät read anything reasonable. How do you thing the characters from your CSV are converted to `float`? Reading a CSV involves much more than binary reading. And always check the rsult of functions wich can report an error relevant for program execution like `malloc` and `fread`.

Comment: it sounds like your csv file is really a text file.  The call to `fread` will not convert the text into floats for you.

Comment: Where is the code to convert numbers expressed as a sequence of digits in base 10 into a `float`? Are you expecting it to happen by magic?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is here. A (single-precision) `float` can store about 9 significant digits. If you want more, then use `double`. (This will consume twice as much memory, however.) You also seem to be mistaken in thinking that `fread()` will parse CSV files for you. It won't. Try `fscanf()` instead.

Comment: Post the code used to create and `fwrite()` the data.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage IEEE-1394 single-precision is only precise to ~7 digits

Answer (score 1):

The `float` type is the least precise of the floating point data types in C. They are [ranked](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) as follows:

- `float`
- `double`
- `long double`

The lengths (in bytes) of each type differ depending on the particular C implementation; the main thing to understand is that each type will have a precision limit, and more precise types take up more space. It is likely that choosing a more precise data type will be good enough for your purposes.

It's impossible to perfectly capture decimal precision with binary numbers. There are certain exact numbers in decimal notation that are infinitely-repeating numbers in binary notation (e.g. 0.2), and print functions will generally only display numbers up to a certain decimal place. The combination of these can mean that numbers can display using either fewer or more decimal places than the original precision of the number.

If precise control over the decimal precision of a number is needed (up to a given degree), it is possible to use [fixed-point notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). This is typically done by including integer values together with a known (and fixed) scaling factor, but requires the arithmetic operations to be modified to account for the scaling factor.